# Efficient mapping for a particular finite integer set

Tags: c, unicode, mapping, bit-manipulation

I'm looking for a small, fast (in both directions) bijective mapping between the following list of integers and a subset of the range 0-127:

```
0x200C, 0x200D, 0x200E, 0x200F,
0x2013, 0x2014, 0x2015, 0x2017,
0x2018, 0x2019, 0x201A, 0x201C,
0x201D, 0x201E, 0x2020, 0x2021,
0x2022, 0x2026, 0x2030, 0x2039,
0x203A, 0x20AA, 0x20AB, 0x20AC,
0x20AF, 0x2116, 0x2122
```

<strike>One obvious solution is:</strike>

```
y = x>>2 & 0x40 | x & 0x3f;
x = 0x2000 | y<<2 & 0x100 | y & 0x3f;
```

**Edit:** I was missing some of the values, particularly 0x20Ax, which don't work with the above.

Another obvious solution is a lookup table, but without making it unnecessarily large, a lookup table would require some bit rearrangement anyway and I suspect the whole task can be better accomplished with simple bit rearrangement.

For the curious, those magic numbers are the only "large" Unicode codepoints that appear in legacy ISO-8859 and Windows codepages.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm

Comment: btw, a bijective mapping onto a subset is called injective ;)

Answer (score 3):

This method uses multiplication in a finite field:

```
#define PRIME 0x119
#define OFFSET1 0x00f
#define OFFSET2 0x200c
#define OFFSET3 (OFFSET2 - OFFSET1)
#define MULTIPLIER 2
#define INVERSE 0x8d

unsigned map(unsigned n)
{
    return ((n - OFFSET3) * MULTIPLIER) % PRIME;
}

unsigned unmap(unsigned m)
{
    return ((m * INVERSE) + PRIME - OFFSET1) % PRIME + OFFSET2;
}
```

`map()` converts the unicode points to the unique 7 bit numbers, and `unmap()` does the reverse.  Note that `gcc` at least is able to compile this to x86 code which does not use any division operations, since the modulus is a constant.

Comment: Did you work this out by hand or do you have a tool to do it? This is definitely the most elegant answer yet to my question as-asked, though I may end up doing something like Jens was talking about and handling *all* characters in these sets with a two-level map.

Comment: @R.: I picked `0x119` as the first prime larger than `0x2122 - 0x200c`, then wrote a short C program to bruteforce the `OFFSET1` and `MULTIPLIER` values that gave the narrowest range.  Since that range was less than `0x7f`, I stopped there and calculated the multiplicative inverse of `2` mod `0x119`.  If `0x119` hadn't worked, I would have gone to the next higher prime.

Comment: a nice, clean approach to the problem; strangely enough, though, my ad-hoc algorithm seems to outperform yours, even though my decoding function looks really ugly...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's ugly, but except for last value all others are already unique if you consider lowest 6 bits, so you can just build and inverse map:

```
int ints[] = {0x200C, 0x200D, 0x200E, 0x200F,
              0x2013, 0x2014, 0x2015, 0x2017,
              0x2018, 0x2019, 0x201A, 0x201C,
              0x201D, 0x201E, 0x2020, 0x2021,
              0x2022, 0x2026, 0x2030, 0x2039,
              0x203A, 0x20AA, 0x20AB, 0x20AC,
              0x20AF, 0x2116, 0x2122};

int invmap[64];

void mkinvmap()
{
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
        invmap[ints[i]&63] = ints[i];
    invmap[0] = 0x2122;
}
```

After this inverse map computation the two transform functions are

```
int direct(int x)  { return x==0x2122 ? 0 : (x & 63); }
int inverse(int x) { return invmap[x]; }
```

The function `direct(x)` will return a number between 0 and 63, and the function `inverse(x)` given a number between 0 and 63 will return an integer. For all the 27 values in your list `inverse(direct(x)) == x`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for some simple (and cheap) hash function `f` that you choose out of a family `f0, f1, ...` of such functions that map to values `0..255`, say. If your hash function would be random, by the birthday paradox you'd have some collisions for the values that you are interested in, but not many.

Now a simple perl (of whatever) script will allow you to preprocess your fixed valued data to reduce (or even eliminate) collisions by choosing an appropriate function from your set.

This approach has the advantage that you can renew the preprocessing run if you find out that you forgot a value (as you already did) or some weird country decides to map bizarre unicode characters like € into an 8bit character set.

And, BTW, I think the amount of special characters that are in some of the iso-8859-? sets must be much larger than what you have, here, no? I'd take them all.

**Edit:** After doing some experiments a little perl script tells me that all 577 unicode code points that appear in one of the iso-8859 encodings map to different positions when reduced modulo 10007 or 10009.

**Edit:** The following table does the trick, for the limited set:

```
wchar_t const uniqTable[91] = {
[0x7] = L'\u2116' /* № */,
[0xD] = L'\uFFFD' /* � */,
[0xE] = L'\u200C' /* ‌ */,
[0xF] = L'\u200D' /* ‍ */,
[0x10] = L'\u200E' /* ‎ */,
[0x11] = L'\u200F' /* ‏ */,
[0x13] = L'\u2122' /* ™ */,
[0x15] = L'\u2013' /* – */,
[0x16] = L'\u2014' /* — */,
[0x17] = L'\u2015' /* ― */,
[0x19] = L'\u2017' /* ‗ */,
[0x1A] = L'\u2018' /* ‘ */,
[0x1B] = L'\u2019' /* ’ */,
[0x1C] = L'\u201A' /* ‚ */,
[0x1E] = L'\u201C' /* “ */,
[0x1F] = L'\u201D' /* ” */,
[0x20] = L'\u201E' /* „ */,
[0x22] = L'\u2020' /* † */,
[0x23] = L'\u2021' /* ‡ */,
[0x24] = L'\u2022' /* • */,
[0x28] = L'\u2026' /* … */,
[0x32] = L'\u2030' /* ‰ */,
[0x3B] = L'\u2039' /* ‹ */,
[0x3C] = L'\u203A' /* › */,
[0x51] = L'\u20AA' /* ₪ */,
[0x52] = L'\u20AB' /* ₫ */,
[0x53] = L'\u20AC' /* € */,
[0x56] = L'\u20AF' /* ₯ */,
};
```

Comment: Most characters in iso-8859-* and windows codepages are in the ranges for their respective alphabets (Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew, Extended Latin, ...), but I was using much larger tables than necessary to accommodate a few rare U+2xxx codes here and there (Euro sign, trademark sign, smart quotes, etc.)

Comment: Ok, I see. But still, instead of having to iterate over the different characters sets, I'd chose a generic solution to capture them all. If you look at the table in https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859, there aren't too many. But perhaps you'd have to hash them in something a bit bigger than I thought, 10 bit should do quite well.

Comment: Indeed 10 bits per entry is enough for most of the legacy character sets, except for the ugly U+2xxx cases. The 0-127 in my question came from the fact that no high bytes can map onto ASCII, so I can reuse numbers in this range as redirections for the U+2xxx characters.

Comment: Which 577 are you talking about? Reduction modulo 10007 or 10009 doesn't sound like it would make them very small; I can already do better than that.

Comment: All code points that appear in one of the iso-8859. I didn't test all prime numbers up to then but something in the range of 4000 didn't do, and these two did. If you'd do such a test just for the code points your are interested in, you'd probably find a much smaller prime number. And then, yes, this would give you a first level table with lot of nothing in it, but you could just store the values `0..127` or so you are interested in.

Comment: @R: `91` does the trick for a set that includes the values that you were looking for. Please, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

By trial & error, I arrived at the following algorithm:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const unsigned CODES[] = {
    0x200C, 0x200D, 0x200E, 0x200F,
    0x2013, 0x2014, 0x2015, 0x2017,
    0x2018, 0x2019, 0x201A, 0x201C,
    0x201D, 0x201E, 0x2020, 0x2021,
    0x2022, 0x2026, 0x2030, 0x2039,
    0x203A, 0x20AA, 0x20AB, 0x20AC,
    0x20AF, 0x2116, 0x2122
};

static unsigned enc(unsigned value)
{
    return (value & 0x3F) + (value & 0x180) / 4;
}

static unsigned dec(unsigned value)
{
    return 0x2000 + value + ((value & 0x40) >> 6) * 3 *
        (0x20 + (value & 0x10) * 2 + (value & 0x20));
}

int main(void)
{
    const unsigned *const END = CODES + sizeof CODES / sizeof *CODES;
    const unsigned *current = CODES;
    for(; current < END; ++current)
    {
        printf("%04x -> %02x -> %04x\n",
            *current, enc(*current), dec(enc(*current)));

        assert(enc(*current) < 0x80);
        assert(dec(enc(*current)) == *current);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes, evolution beats intelligent design even when writing code ;)

Comment: The output of `enc` is a lot bigger than 127.